# How to remote-desktop RaspberryPi on windows device via ethernet without router

Tags: remote-desktop, ethernet, raspberry-pi, vnc

I need a way to be able to access the RaspberryPi in a similar way to remote desktop by using an ethernet cable. I would like to be able to do this without internet dependancy as I have tried some already and due to my Unis internet set up it is too slow, also I cannot always depend on it but I need to be able to access the RasberryPi whenever.

So far I have tried various methods online such as VNC and SSH but none of them have worked correctly due to either out of date instructions, no windows instructions or some other problem crops up.

I wondered if anyone knew of a way to solve this problem I'm having and could explain it. My desktop and laptop are windows out of convince and I need a solution that I can carry out on them.
RaspberryPi is running Raspbian.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The simplest *"remote desktop"* from a Windows PC to a Linux machine would be a telnet connection.  But you're not clear as to what you're trying to do and what you have.  Describing what you can't or won't do and what you don't have is not an adequate description.

Answer (score 0):

You can install `xrdp` on Raspbian and configure a fixed IP in the Raspberry Pi.

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get upgrade  
sudo apt-get install xrdp tightvncserver
```

Now reboot the system, and then you can use the Microsoft Remote Desktop application for Windows or MacOS to connect to your Raspberry Pi.

Raspbian includes `avahi` server and you can connect to the Raspberry using his `Host Name`, usually is: `raspberrypi.local` without knowing the IP address.

Comment: With new Raspbian versions you can use `apt` with better progress information than `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution for myself.

I find the ipv4 address for the Ethernet on the raspberry pi and use it in putty and it connects fine.
This allows me to connect to my raspberry pi on my laptop with an Ethernet cable whether I have internet or not.

Thanks for the other answers though.

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi uses X-11, which natively supports remote access.
All you need to do is install an X server on your local machine.  For Linux machines, or other Raspberry use `apt-get install xserver-xephyr`. This installs a local X display server that can connect to most any Linux remote through SSH, without installing anything new on the remote.

I then start Xephyr locally, and then ssh to the remote. I get a full desktop locally served.  This means I can configure the remote Pi to boot without a desktop server.

---

On the local machine:

```
$  Xephyr -ac -screen 1728x972  -br -host-cursor -reset -terminate  :3.0 &

$  xterm -display :3.0 &
```

then in the xterm within the Xephyr window (use appropriate IP):

```
$  ssh -XfC pi@111.111.1.1  exec  startlxde
```

or

```
$  ssh -XfC pi@111.111.1.1  exec  startlxde-pi
```

---

This will bring up a full desktop generated on the remote pi, but served on the local machine, in the screen resolution of the local machine. -- NOTHING to install on the remote Pi!

From a local Windows machine, I have used Cygwin (xterminal) and Putty also has an X-server.  I haven't used either in several years.  I believe there are other X-server applications that run on Windows.  'X-server', 'serves' a display.  The X-client is the program you are running remotely.  All X-11 Linux/Unix systems, use this, they just have the X-server running on it's own hardware serving the image on the local hardware.